# MATH LOGIC :: proof that fourmula is derivable. Use Axioms

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Without using completeness theorem, proof that fourmula  ( → ( → )) ↔ (¬ ∨ ¬ ∨ )  is derivable. Use Axioms
A→(B→A),
(A→(B→C))→((A→B)→(A→C)),
A∧B→A,
A∧B→B,
A→(B→(A∧B)),
A→A∨B,
B→A∨B,
(A→C)→((B→C)→(A∨B→C)),
¬A→(A→B),
(A→B)→((A→¬B)→¬A),
A∨¬A.

Comment: As there is no axiom involving $↔$ this is impossible.

Comment: You can use axiom with -> from left to right and then from right to left

Comment: So do you want to prove that two different formulas are derivable?

Comment: Yes, prove both way. and it will be enough

Comment: No one will blame you for adding $(A \to B) \to ((B \to A) \to (A \leftrightarrow B))$ as an axiom

Comment: I am still not clear: is $↔$ a symbol of the language or is it not? If it is, then you need axioms involving $↔$  before you can give a derivation of the formula. If it is not, then the thing you write isn't a formula, and you must say exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Given that is says "formula ... is derivable" it really looks like it's just one formula and additional axioms are indeed needed. But you're right ... maybe they are simple asking for a proof of equivalence .. which can be done by two formal proofs of consequence

Comment: Guys I translated this task from another language, maybe I misused some words.But Here wer need to prove from left to right and right to left, using axioms

Comment: If you add axiom (A→B)→((B→A)→(A↔B)) you need to prove it the same way (left - > right && right->left) and then only use

Comment: @WOL-THEWORLDOFLESSONS Correct

Comment: @Bram28 , I can't correct it.I did my best. I already said the main idea of task.

Comment: @WOL-THEWORLDOFLESSONS You mean (ignoring the whole $\leftrightarrow$ issue) you can't prove either direction?  Can you at least post your attempts/incomplete proofs, or even just your thoughts in your post? People on this site never like it when the OP doesn't show any work at all .... makes it look like you're just hoping for us to do your HW ... and that's why you're getting the 'close' votes ....

Comment: @WOL-THEWORLDOFLESSONS Also ... are you allowed to use the Deduction Theorem?

Comment: Yes. I'm allowed. I tried to solve it by myself...but I don't thing that it's the kind of task when my attempts can help others

Comment: All formulas from here https://ibb.co/1TdWGXD

Comment: Showing your attempts will surely help other see what you understand and where you are having trouble. @WOL-THEWORLDOFLESSONS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the comparatively simple subproofs for $\def\to{{\rightarrow}}\def\lor{{\vee}}\rm B\to C\dashv\vdash \lnot B\lor C$.

You should see that $\rm B\to C\vdash \lnot B\lor C$ can be proven, via *disjunction elimination* and the *law of excluded middle* [ie axiom $a\lor\lnot a$], *should* we have proofs for $\rm B\to C\vdash B\to( \lnot B\lor C )$ and $\rm~\vdash\lnot B\to(\lnot B\lor C)$, so we just need to validate those.   Well, the second is axiomatic [$a\to(a\lor b)$], and and the first just takes a little work.

The other direction, $\rm\lnot B\lor C\vdash B\to C$ is almost trivial, since $\rm~\vdash\lnot B\to(B\to C)$ and $\rm~\vdash C\to(B\to C)$ are axiomatic [$\lnot a\to(a\to b)$ and $a\to (b\to a)$], thus we can again use *disjunction elimination* [which corresponds to axiom $(a\to c)\to((b\to c)\to((a\lor b)\to c)~$].

Then you can expand this on foundation to prove $\rm A\to(B\to C)\dashv\vdash \lnot A\lor\color{silver}(\lnot B\lor C\color{silver})$ .